# What is a good synth for a beginner to learn on?

Tags: synthesizer, gear, production, beginner, buying-stuff

I'm getting into production and song writing, and want a proper synth to learn on.  I've played around with VSTs, but I don't feel very engaged with them - I don't feel like I can play them like an instrument.  I have a Korg Volca Keys, which is excellent, but I feel I've reached the limits of what it can do sound-wise.

I've been looking at stuff like the Bass Station II, Minilogue/Monologue and the Roland Boutique series.  Do you guys have any recommendations for a synth with loads of knobs that I can really get to grips with synthesis on?

Edit: my budget would be around £500

Comment: You should say how much you are planning to spend, because you can't expect the same thing from a $300 and a $1900 synth... Also what kind of sound do you like?

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq I'm thinking around £500, but I'm somewhat flexible on that

Comment: This might be a controversial opinion but I think anything without presets will force you to learn because you will not be able to save a sound you like. You will have to remember how to make it each time you need it.

Comment: I bought a Moog Minitaur to do exactly the same thing as you. I was absolutely blown away by the sound of it! I actually wanted something that didn't have 'loads of knobs' though, as I thought it might complicate the learning process. You can get really overwhelmed by complicated synths quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your tastes or your budget, but I think you could only be satisfied with something like the [Arturia MatrixBrute](https://www.arturia.com/products/matrixbrute/overview). Lots of knobs and countless possibilities. But it comes at a price: about 2000€. It's a very good investment though because you could keep it forever.

I also remember having fun with [Sequential Circuits Prophet-5](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_Circuits_Prophet_5) but I have no idea of the price today.

It all depends on your taste and budget. If you're about to spend £500 then I think the Bass Station II is a very good choice. The question is quite subjective though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of decent options for your budget.

Here's some in no particular order:

- Moog Minitaur
- Doepfer Dark Energy
- Waldorf blofeld
- Dreadbox Erebus
- Roland System 1

I assume you already have a midi keyboard so the 1st 4 are expanders (don't have keys).